# Reasons for questions of this type to be downvoted?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

[This question on music licensing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/96049/what-are-the-licensing-terms-for-portal-2s-soundtrack/96051#comment131408_96051) has been downvoted a few times. Being relatively new to Arqade, I'd like to know why so I can avoid it in the future.

The question is on licensing for a game's music (for reuse in another game) rather than gameplay itself, despite the heavy 'gaming' tendancies, **is this considered too off-topic by the community?**
If not, what are some reasons it would be voted down?

I tried to keep it short, factual, and clearly answerable. The resulting answer was quite clear-cut and I feel useful to the community.

Any advice or suggestions for future questions much appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for coming to meta to ask about it. :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question you asked is not about playing a video game or operating video game related hardware. As such, it is not really on topic for this site, so I voted to close it.

Your question in particular is basically "What are the terms for using this copyrighted work in something I am creating?", which is in no way particularly related to video games *and* depends on the policy of the company that owns the copyrighted work. The first problem makes it off topic for the site and the second makes it not a good question for the network because the only people qualified to answer it are a subset of the people that work for the company, not experts on any particular topic.

Comment: OK, thanks for explaining, I mistakenly assumed the link to video-gaming was enough for relevancy but I see how tenuous that is in light of our response.